# Parsing date object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var formattedDate = new Date(parseInt(thisObj.Patient.DateOfBirth.substr(6)));
```

When i print my Date Object, i get this as output.

```
Wed May 04 2011 09:30:00 GMT+0530 (GMT+05:30)
```

How can i separate May, 04 and 2011 into separate variables like

```
var Month = May;
var Date = 04;
var Year = 2011;
```

How i can also check whether the Age of the person is below one year or not.

Comment: Using integrated IDEs (like netbeans) can help you in finding methods of lots of objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object has many handy methods - use them.

[Date Object on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

- `getDate()`: returns the day of the month (from 1-31)
- `getFullYear()`: returns the year (four digits)
- `getMonth()`: returns the month (from 0-11)

Answer (score 2):

You can only access the numerical values, you have to format them yourself then. Use `Date.getFullYear()`, `Date.getMonth()` etc. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date for documentation of this object.

You can compare dates by subtracting them:

```
alert(new Date() - formattedDate);
```

This will show the number of milliseconds between current date and `formattedDate`. Now you only need to know the number of milliseconds in a year.

Answer (score 1):

Try using these three:

```
formattedDate.getYear() .getMonth() .getDay()
```

Comment: `getYear` is deprecated (and has been for many years), you should use `getFullYear`.